# What is the syntax for passing a storage image as descriptor?

Tags: c++, graphics, glsl, vulkan, compute-shader

I have created a swapchain with images, and corresponding image views. I want to pass them to a compute shader which will modify them on a per pixel basis, and then present them. So, I created a descriptor set to modify them which appears to be how to do it, however, I don't know how exactly I format it on the opengl side, which seems to be causing this error.

```cpp
        auto computeShaderCode = readFile("Square.spv");
        vk::ShaderModuleCreateInfo shaderModuleCreateInfo {
            {},
            computeShaderCode.size(),
            reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(computeShaderCode.data())
        };
        vk::ShaderModule shaderModule = device.createShaderModule(shaderModuleCreateInfo);
        // Create descriptor set layout
        std::vector<vk::DescriptorSetLayoutBinding> descriptorSetLayoutBindings;
        uint32_t i = 0;
        for (auto image : swapchainImages) {
            vk::DescriptorSetLayoutBinding swapchainImageDescriptorLayoutBinding {
                i,
                vk::DescriptorType::eStorageImage, 
                1, 
                vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eCompute
            };
            i++;
            descriptorSetLayoutBindings.push_back(swapchainImageDescriptorLayoutBinding);
        };
        vk::DescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo(
            {},
            descriptorSetLayoutBindings
        );
        vk::DescriptorSetLayout descriptorSetLayout = device.createDescriptorSetLayout(descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo);
        // Create pipeline
        vk::PipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutCreateInfo = { {}, descriptorSetLayout };
        vk::PipelineLayout pipelineLayout = device.createPipelineLayout(pipelineLayoutCreateInfo);
        vk::PipelineCache pipelineCache = device.createPipelineCache({});
        vk::PipelineShaderStageCreateInfo pipelineShaderStageCreateInfo {
            {},
            vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eCompute,
            shaderModule, 
            "main"
        };
        vk::ComputePipelineCreateInfo computePipelineCreateInfo {
            {},
            pipelineShaderStageCreateInfo,
            pipelineLayout
        };
        computePipeline = device.createComputePipeline(pipelineCache, computePipelineCreateInfo).value;
        // Create descriptor pool
        vk::DescriptorPoolSize descriptorPoolSize { vk::DescriptorType::eStorageImage, 2 };
        vk::DescriptorPoolCreateInfo descriptorPoolCreateInfo {
            {}, 
            1,
            descriptorPoolSize
        };
        vk::DescriptorPool descriptorPool = device.createDescriptorPool(descriptorPoolCreateInfo);
        // Allocate descriptor set
        vk::DescriptorSetAllocateInfo descriptorSetAllocateInfo { descriptorPool, 1, &descriptorSetLayout };
        const std::vector<vk::DescriptorSet> descriptorSets = device.allocateDescriptorSets(descriptorSetAllocateInfo);
        vk::DescriptorSet descriptorSet = descriptorSets.front();
        std::vector<vk::DescriptorImageInfo> imageInfos;
        std::vector<vk::WriteDescriptorSet> writeDescriptorSets;
        i = 0;
        for (auto image : swapchainImages) {
            vk::DescriptorImageInfo imageInfo {
                VK_NULL_HANDLE,
                swapchainImageViews[i]
            };
            writeDescriptorSets.push_back({
                descriptorSet,
                i,
                (uint32_t) 0,
                (uint32_t) 1,
                vk::DescriptorType::eStorageImage,
                &imageInfo
            });
            i++;
        }
        device.updateDescriptorSets(writeDescriptorSets, {});
```

this is the code of the function to make the compute shader

```c
#version 450
layout (local_size_x = 1) in;
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) buffer  InputBuffer{
    int stuff[];
} inputData;
layout(set = 0, binding = 1) buffer  OutputBuffer{
    int stuff[];
} outputData;
void main () {
    uint gID = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    outputData.stuff[gID] = inputData.stuff[gID] / inputData.stuff[gID] + 3153;
}
```

this is the code of the compute shader I have so far, which throws this error:

```
VUID-VkComputePipelineCreateInfo-layout-00703(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -432263797 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkComputePipelineCreateInfo-layout-00703 ] Object 0: handle = 0x1ede0385278, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xe63c2d8b | Type mismatch on descriptor slot 0.0 (expected `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER_DYNAMIC`) but descriptor of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE The Vulkan spec states: layout must be consistent with the layout of the compute shader specified in stage (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.216.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkComputePipelineCreateInfo-layout-00703)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x1ede0385278, type: 3, name: NULL
VUID-VkComputePipelineCreateInfo-layout-00703(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -432263797 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkComputePipelineCreateInfo-layout-00703 ] Object 0: handle = 0x1ede0385278, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xe63c2d8b | Type mismatch on descriptor slot 0.1 (expected `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER_DYNAMIC`) but descriptor of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE The Vulkan spec states: layout must be consistent with the layout of the compute shader specified in stage (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.216.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkComputePipelineCreateInfo-layout-00703)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x1ede0385278, type: 3, name: NULL
vk::Device::allocateDescriptorSets: ErrorOutOfPoolMemory
```

I'm pretty sure this error is saying that the compute shader code, and the attempted allocation of descriptor sets do not match, so it will not be doing that. However, I do not know the syntax of storage images going shaders
PS: it's using `vulkan.hpp`

Answer (score 1):

Your descriptor setup is fine, as you already set and supply images. The error is caused by your shader, which clearly refers to buffers and not images. If you want to use storage images in your compute shader, the syntax should look like this:

```c
layout (set = 0, binding = 0, rgba8) uniform readonly image2D inputImage;
layout (set = 0, binding = 1, rgba8) uniform image2D outputImage;
```

Note: While OpenGL's GLSL syntax slightly differs from Vulkan's, both are very similar. So a good starting point for learning GLSL language basiscs is https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language.